# Getting the data retrieved by SqlDataSource (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, caching, sqldatasource

I have a SqlDataSource retrieve tabular data from a store procedure. How can I get to the data it retrieved in order to save it to the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code-behind, you can run the "Select" method on the SqlDataSource to get the data.  If you are binding the SqlDataSource to a control, it will automatically call select when rendering the control, but you can also call it by hand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select.aspx